# Как загрузить всю таблицу с сайта?

Tags: python, html, requests, beautiful-soup

Здраствуйте.
Хочу запарсить сайта с таблицей в которой результаты экзаменов.
Проблема в том, что сначала в таблице только 10 столбцов, что бы загрузить всю надо нажать на кнопку `Загрузить еще`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код написал который берет этих 10 человек:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://vstup.osvita.ua/y2021/r14/97/833553')
element = driver.find_element_by_class_name('detail-link')
element.click()

r = requests.get('https://vstup.osvita.ua/y2021/r14/97/833553')

html = BS(r.content, 'html.parser')
trs = html.select('.rstatus6')
for el in trs:
    t = el.find_all('td')

    print(t[0].text)
    print(t[1].text)
    print(t[2].text)
    print(t[3].text)
    print(t[4].text)
    print(t[5].text)

    print('\n')
    print('\n')
```

Но вот как дальше не могу понять. Питаюсь сделать через `selenium` но кнопка как то сильно спрятана.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ну и само собой выдает ошибку:

```
Message: element click intercepted: Element <div class="detail-link" onclick="">...</div> is not clickable at point (509, 670). Other element would receive the click: <iframe allowfullscreen="true" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" hidefocus="true" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" mozallowfullscreen="true" msallowfullscreen="true" oallowfullscreen="true" scrolling="no" tabindex="-1" webkitallowfullscreen="true" title="iframe" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; border: 0px; margin: 0px auto; top: 0px; left: 0px; position: absolute;"></iframe>
  (Session info: chrome=91.0.4472.124)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Выполни команду **getItemsRequest()** в консоли через Selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

def browser_chrome():
    options = Options()
    #options.add_argument('headless')
    options.add_argument('window-size=1920x935')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\путь\chromedriver.exe', options=options)
    driver.get('https://vstup.osvita.ua/y2021/r14/97/833553')
    driver.execute_script('getItemsRequest()') # Нажимает кнопку
    time.sleep(5)
    body = driver.execute_script('return document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]') 
    html_page = body.get_attribute('innerHTML')
    html = BS(html_page, 'html.parser')
    trs = html.select('.rstatus6')
    for el in trs:
        t = el.find_all('td')
        print(f'{t[0].text}|{t[1].text}|{t[2].text}')

browser_chrome()
```

Comment: Это вызов функции "Завантажити ще..."

Comment: Можете показать как это выглядит в коде?

Comment: Да, могу, 5 минут

Comment: Божее, чел, спасибо тебе, уже дня 2 сижу не понимаю как сделать.
Огромное спасибо

Comment: Всегда рад помочь)

Answer (score 0):

У меня подобный вопрос. Что если нужно парсить много страниц с данного ресурса. На одних есть "Завантажити ще", а на других нет. Подскажите, как реализовать driver.execute_script('getItemsRequest()') Исходя из таких условий. Например, используя if? Заранее благодарна